# How to interpret my neural network with high accuracy but low probability in results

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I have built a classical ANN using keras which provides probability (using sigmoid function) of the outcomes (0 or 1). While the accuracy of the model is high when the model is fit ~90%, the outcome probability of the test set results is very poor. How can I interpret this?

## Build ANN

```
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Dense(activation="relu",input_dim=7,kernel_initializer="uniform", units = 4))
classifier.add(Dense(activation="relu",kernel_initializer="uniform", units = 4))
classifier.add(Dense(activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer="uniform", units = 1))
classifier.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy",metrics=['accuracy'])
classifier.fit(X_train,y_train, batch_size=10,epochs=100)
```

## Predict results:

```
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

I have attached the test set results where result probabilities can be seen.
[image: Test Set Plot]
My immediate questions:

1. I have used standard scaler to preprocess the data. Do I need to de-scale the y_pred before I understand the result?
2. Given the high accuracy of the model, why I am seeing the distributed probabilities on the chart, which eventually makes it not useful. How do I tweak it further
   Thanks!

Comment: for Data science/machine learning question, go to : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/
For your problem : if your train accuracy is high and your test accuracy is low => overfittng. I let you google it, and find information about it, or ask your question in the site I linked. + I don't understand your plot at all.

Comment: thank you for the direction. I will post my query on the other portal. Plot show probabilities vs. frequency